# how to transfer column names to replace the number in the colums in presto

Tags: sql, presto

so here is my problem,
below is the current table

```
|userid|tv1|tv2|tv3
|123|0|1|2
|125|1|2|0
```

so I want it to be look like:

```
|userid|tv
|123|tv2
|123|tv3
|123|tv3
|125|tv1
|125|tv2
|125|tv2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`repeat`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#repeat) + [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest)

```
SELECT userid, productid
FROM your_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(repeat('tv1', tv1) || repeat('tv2', tv2) || repeat('tv3', tv3)) t(productid);
```

Note that a user with all zeroes will not be part of the output.
If you want to keep users will all zeroes, you can do so since since **Presto 319** (will be released next week):

```
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(....) t(productid) ON true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a table of numbers.  For small numbers, something like this:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3
     )
select userid, 'tv1' as tv
from t join
     n
     on t.tv1 <= n.n
union all
select userid, 'tv2' as tv
from t join
     n
     on t.tv2 <= n.n
union all
select userid, 'tv3' as tv
from t join
     n
     on t.tv3 <= n.n;
```

The numbers table needs to be big enough to handle the largest values in the table.

Comment: this part seems not right
with n as (
      select 1 as n union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3
     )

Comment: What do you find to be the problem.  It works in most databases.